# Getting beautifulsoup to run for python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get beautifulsoup to run on my Mac, it's not working, and I'm at my wits end.  It seems really easy to install, which is even more maddening.

I'm running Python version 3.5.1

I'm a newbie at Python - have spent the last hour working through python documentation and other stack overflow, but haven't found a working solution yet.

Here's the code (the sys path line is required because that's where it installed when I ran pip install beautifulsoup4)

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages")

import beautifulsoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""

soup = beautifulsoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Here's the error I get:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Great.  So then I found some advice that said "You are importing the module which contains classes, functions etc. In order to instantiate a BeautifulSoup class instance form the BeautifulSoup module you need to either import it or use the full name including the module prefix like yonili suggests in the comment above"

[What does "module object is not callable" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444500/what-does-module-object-is-not-callable-mean)

So I change the code to read:

```
beautifulsoup.beautifulsoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Now I get this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'beautifulsoup' has no attribute 'beautifulsoup'
```

I also tried

```
from beautifulsoup import beautifulsoup
```

Which gave me error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup'
```

Lastly I tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And I got the error

```
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Comment: I don't think that first line of code is necessary unless you somehow are installing python packages to your user folder

Comment: Did you `pip install beautifulsoup4`?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3368295/5299236), but I'd suggest update your BeautifulSoup to 4 and do what the below answers say anyway.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes line of code is necessary because even though I'm on python 3, it installed in a python 2.7 folder.  

yes I did

Comment: How are you running python? If it's from an editor, the editor might have a different python on it's path than pip. From where you run pip (probably the Terminal), run the command `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`; from the editor, add an `import sys` line and the same `print(sys.executable)` line. Are the two installation paths the same?

Comment: You are using a Mac? Then why is there (or why do you manually need to reference) a Python site-packages directory in your User Library? That was my point. I don't think the system python installs to there. And if you are using Python3, then you'll want `pip3 install`

Comment: @Ben no - can I change my terminal path to match editor?

terminal: /usr/bin/python
editor: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5

Comment: @CBA what editor are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

If using BeautifulSoup 4, you need to import like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Additionally, you can use `import * as *`

e.g

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as somename
```

Comment: I was just going to edit my question about this.  When I do that, I get this error: ImportError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: I checked pip freeze and it says beautifulsoup4==4.4.1

Comment: Just did pip install bs4.  Now pip freeze says bs4==0.0.1.  But still get no module named bs4 error

Comment: I think `pip3` needs used, and `beautifulsoup4` is the correct package.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bs4

Answer (score 1):

In oder to [install `BeautifulSoup` version 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup), use:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then, you would be able to import it as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```